# Is it worth using angular.js on a multilingual website running on a CMS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, content-management-system, multilingual

I have been reading about Angular.js on blogs and such and I'm quite hyped to delve into it. The problem I'm facing with my decision is if it works well with a CMS based site.

I mostly develop CMS (Drupal mostly) centric websites, getting the sensitive data via REST API calls from a java backend. I only use the content management, security and localization management of a CMS. All the UI manipulation and form submission is being done via jQuery.

The problem I have with jQuery is that on some UI and Form validation intensive pages, the jQuery code can go up to a 1000 lines of code, which is very hard to maintain and test. Such examples are payment pages, where the user is given a choice to select a payment provider to place a payment and each payment has a wide range of field validations.

I would love to use Angular but I'm afraid it will become too complicated due to the fact that I work on multilingual sites. Sure I can control the CMS purely from REST, but wouldn't it feel a bit like reinventing the wheel?

Would love to know if Angular.js would work well on multilingual CMS based sites.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you need to move all your CMS as a real Content Management System and only for content and don't mix the paradigms. Then expose the "content" aka DATA in REST API in order to be consumed by the AngularJS app.

Means that are have to be separated applications to achieve the real Single Page Applications approach. It may can be benefit you on some points and recieve some harm on some other (such as SEO) in your architecture.